# Meteor bootstrap datetimepicker throwing errors and positioned incorrectly

Tags: meteor, bootstrap-datepicker, meteor-autoform

I'm getting the following errors and positioning in the screen shot below when I use the [autoform bootstrap datepicker](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform-bs-datetimepicker).

[image]

Error:

2meteor.js:887 Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at null. (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform-bs-datetimepicker.js?279246d1cf7d4b5603ac030d7466e9bc6e5ac0d1:171:11)

Here is the code I have:

Packages:

```
aldeed:autoform                     # Auto create forms with validations from schema (Uses bootstrap by default).
twbs:bootstrap                      # Bootstrap.
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker     # Bootstrap datetime picker.
aldeed:autoform-bs-datetimepicker   # Add datetime picker to autoform.
```

Schema:

```
   start:
      type: Date
      label: 'Start'
      autoform:
         type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker'
   end:
      type: Date
      label: 'End'
      autoform:
         type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker'
```

Form:

```
   +autoForm(collection='Events' id='insertEventForm' type='insert')
      fieldset
         legend Add an event
         +afQuickField(name='start')
         +afQuickField(name='end')
         +afQuickField(name='assignedToId')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm missing I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure but I remember that once I had a error in the console and I only had to specify the latest versions of the packages. Maybe this is the case.

Comment: Thanks @Mário. I tried updating everything and still have the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a container div around of the controls

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              your code snippet here
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. That fixed the positioning. I'm still getting the meteor errors though. They still prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: "undefined is not a function" is not very helpful as this error can come from anywhere, can you maybe put your code on github or meteorpad to debug?

Comment: I agree. Sorry about that. If I can't figure it out I will put it on Meteorpad.

Comment: Ok good luck and let me know if you want me to debug on meteorpad later